# How do I filter dictionary array with search bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, searchbar

I'm getting an array of users called "users" from Firebase and it looks like this when I print it:

```
    {
    bob = 7CEp1NHkc7S7sQ9HYBryB2;
    fred = 4VJs2drJK0ObJUS6mIElD43;
    sarah = B6WI1BXd4cwYkYneEvPBV2;
}
```

I want to get the search working so that if I type a letter, or backspace a letter, it updates instantly.  I think it's almost working but the problem i'm having is with the filterContentForSearchText function.  Right now it looks like this:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText:String, scope:String = "All") {
    filteredUsers = users.filter{user in return

        user.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)

    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

"users" is what I printed out at the beginning of the question. Currently when I type in the search box it just keeps giving me all 3 results no matter what I type so I think I need to fix the filtering function.  I can provide more info if needed but I think the rest is working.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong user is your `Dictionary`. So you will have to first fetch all the keys i.e your username (as it appears from your dictionary contents) and then match searchText with those usernames.